# Maximum 25 pages when printing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, model-view-controller

When more than 25 documents are selected for a multi-document print, all documents are 'squished' on to 25 pages. I cannot find anywhere how this limit is created within code or externally in the printer driver. I am using printThis.js to print. With 25 or fewer documents, the print outs look fine and the page break works fine. The documents are recursively added to an element section that is hidden until ready to print the entire collection.

Check printer driver settings
Checked 3rd party plug in printThis.js

Each document should have its own page. It is as if the page break disappears when more than 25 documents selected. The 25 page print limit escapes me.

Comment: unclear what you are doing to join the documents.

Comment: They are a series of HTML documents that contain page breaks between each one. printThis.js keeps all the CSS formatting for printing so the documents match what is displayed on screen.